# Are semaphore functions down() and __down() same?

Tags: function, linux-kernel, semaphore

In the down function of semaphore code, are the two functions `down(struct semaphore *sem)` at line 53 and `__down(sem)` at line 61.

In the else part are we calling the down at line 53 in a recursive manner.

```
void down(struct semaphore *sem)
{
      unsigned long flags;

      raw_spin_lock_irqsave(&sem->lock, flags);
      if (likely(sem->count > 0))
              sem->count--;
      else
              __down(sem);
     raw_spin_unlock_irqrestore(&sem->lock, flags);
}
EXPORT_SYMBOL(down);
```

[Link to semaphore.c](http://www.linux.fm/source/kernel/semaphore.c/)

Comment: I do not see any recursion anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Are semaphore functions `down()` and `__down()` same?

No they are not. Functions with a `__` prefix are for internal use and should generally not be used in your code.

Taking a short look at the code reveals that `down()` is a function calling `__down()` with a spinlock, protecting the `count` part of the `struct semaphore`.

The function `__down()` is only called if the smaphore's count is `<= 0`, `__down()` delegates to `__down_common()`, that handles the waiting tasks.

So you will never want to call `__down()` directly, if you do so, you will most likely create bugs.

Comment: so sorry to trouble u but i dont understand this part .."down() is a function wrapping __down()"

Comment: In the `down()` function, the `__down()` function is called only if the `count` part is zero. So wrapping might not be the right term, i will correct that in my answer.